# Is the following safe to do?

Tags: c++, inheritance, undefined-behavior

Consider this code:

```
struct A {};

struct B
{
    B(A* a) : a(a) {}
private:
    A* a;
};

struct base
{
    base(B b) : b(b) {}
protected:
    A a;
private:
    B b;
};

struct derived : public base
{
    derived() : base(B(&a)) // <-- IS THIS OK?
    {}
};
```

Here, the base class needs a B object passed to its constructor by the derived class, and the B object refers to an A object, but the A object lives inside the base class.

The constructor of the B object does not do anything to the A pointer except store it, so I'm thinking this should be OK, but it still feels wrong because technically the A object doesn't yet exist at the time I'm passing it to the base constructor.

Can I get into trouble doing this or should this be OK?

Comment: Safe as long as 'a' (like you have marked) is a member of 'struct derived' - ensure 'a' out lives object of struct derived

Comment: Don't use conflicting variable names like that, or the maintainer of this code is in for a world of hurt.

Comment: I was going to say the types don't match at first, but I remembered about implicit consruction. The `explicit` keyword ought to have been implicit with an `implicit` keyword taking over its place.

Comment: @BenVoigt: where are there conflicting variable names?

Comment: @trinithis: where is there implicit construction happening?

Comment: Whoops, nevermind. I mentally parsed `B` as `base` :D. Anycase, implicit construction is a wart.

Comment: HighCommander4: Your *ctor-initializer-lists* use the same identifier to refer to different variables within the same line.  That's horrible style.

Comment: @BenVoigt: On the contrary, I think that's very clean. The compiler knows exactly which variable is being referred to in this context, and the reader knows exactly what is happening - the member variables of the structure/class are being initialized by constructor arguments of the same type. Why would I come up with different names for what are essentially the same variables?

Comment: @HighCommander4: It's a maintenance nightmare.  What if a parameter name were ever changed?  Now the class member will be initialized from itself, and no compiler error.  Using the same name for different objects is a bad idea.  "Essentially the same" they certainly aren't, the lifetimes are totally different.  And no it isn't clear to a reader, I had to go read the standard to make sure what you were doing actually was legal and not a vendor-specific extension.

Comment: @HighCommander4: Add the that the fact that you have a mixture, in one class `a` inside the initializer expression means a parameter, in another it does mean the class member, and I'm having trouble thinking of ways to obfuscate the code any worse.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The days when we had to use prefixes and such to differentiate local variables, member variables, and so on, are gone. We now have IDE's, which colour variables of diferrent scope differently, and which change all uses of a variable when you rename it.

Comment: @HighCommander4: Not necessarily prefixes.  How about `collection() : size(initial_size) {}`, etc.  But if prefixes are the only way you can find to differentiate a name, that's still preferable to reuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is safe as long as you don't *use* `a` in `B`'s constructor, as the object `a` isn't constructed yet.

I mean, you shouldn't dereference the pointer `a` in `B's` constructor; however  after `base`'s constructor is executed, you can safely dereference `B::a` in other methods of `B`.

Comment: You mean, as long as I don't use `a` in `B`'s *constructor*. It should be OK to use `a` elsewhere in `B`, right?

Comment: @HighCommander4: Yes. I just wrote that. After `B` constructor is executed, you can safely use `a` in other methods of `B`.

Comment: @HighCommander4: Or `B`'s destructor, since the temporary `B` variable will be destroyed before `a` is constructed.

Comment: @Nawaz I think that should be: "After `base`s constructor is executed, you can safely use `B::a` in other methods of `B`."

Comment: @bames53: Yup. That is more accurate. I meant the same thing in fact, but somehow skipped my mind. Anyway, edited my post.

Comment: Actually, I think it's a tiny bit more accurate to say that you can safely use `B::a` after the `base` ctor has started (after the open brace).  At that point `base::a` has been constructed.  I suppose you could even use it in `B`'s copy-ctor (if there were a non-implicit one), but that's getting pretty close to the edge...

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I hope the OP reads your comment with which I agree.

Comment: @Nawaz: I'm not sure if I do - I hope he doesn't actually try to take advantage of any of this...

Answer (score 4):

`a` has not been constructed, but it does have an address, and it is legal to take its address at this point.  You do need to be sure, though, not to use the pointer in the constructor of `B` (i.e., don't dereference the pointer).

This is all rather awkward, though.

Comment: Does any of this change if I use a reference instead of a pointer?